# Quais as vantagens de usar a função sprintf do PHP?

Tags: php, string, funções, estilo-de-codificação, concatenação-de-string

Consigo enxergar uma vantagem em utilizar a função [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) no lugar da concatenação: a legibilidade. Além da legibilidade, quais as outras vantagens de `sprintf()` em relação a concatenação? Existe alguma vantagem na hora de traduzir aplicações?

Comment: Legibilidade dependendo do caso né? Não consigo imaginar que um `sprintf` seja mais legivel que um `echo "Nome: $nome";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não concordo que seja uma questão de comparar qual é melhor e nem necessariamente qual as vantagens de uma sob a outra, `sprintf()` pode até parecer "mais fácil" ou vantajoso, mas o que define isto é **a necessidade**, então a vantagem é quando "for necessário", não estou dizendo que vai ter desvantagens em usar deliberadamente, realmente não vai ter "grandes perdas".

A questão é que tanto `sprintf` quanto `printf` fazem **muito mais** do juntar e popular uma string, elas possuem diferentes recursos que podem ser úteis em diferentes situações, por exemplo adicionar zeros a frente de datas:

```
<?php

$dia = 1;
$mes = 5;
$ano = 2019;

$hora = 2;
$minutos = 3;

printf('%02d/%02d/%04d - %02d:%02d', $dia, $mes, $ano, $hora, $minutos);
```

Isto facilita, porque sem o printf/sprintf você precisaria usar `str_pad` ou até ifs para checar, exemplo:

```
$dia = 1;
$mes = 5;
$ano = 2019;

$hora = 2;
$minutos = 3;

$dia = str_pad($dia, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$mes = str_pad($mes, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$ano = str_pad($ano, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$hora = str_pad($hora, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$minutos = str_pad($minutos, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo "$dia/$mes/$ano - $hora:$minutos";
```

neste caso é bem evidente o quanto você pode facilitar a escrita e até o entendimento do código usando printf/sprintf, agora em um simples cenário, apenas "popular" os valores em uma string, sem precisar ajustar os tais valores você pode simplesmente fazer o uso de aspas duplas.

Existe a conversa de que aspas simples (apóstrofos) são mais eficientes que aspas duplas, mas a vantagem performática é tão insignificante ou muitas vezes inexistente que fazer isto:

```
echo 'Horário de hoje', $hora, ':', $minutos, ' - data: ', $dia, '/', $mes, '/', $ano;
```

Não tem vantagem sobre fazer isto:

```
echo "Horário de hoje $hora:$minutos - data: $dia/$mes/$ano";
```

Mesmos em testes de estresse com muitos dados não consegui notar grandes diferenças. Voltando a questão da pergunta, por exemplo se precisar escapar tags HTML para entidades (evitando "injeção de html" que não poderia ocorrer) você terá que usar `htmlspecialchars` e neste caso vai ter que tratar variável por variável, até aonde sei o `sprintf` não irá conseguir resolver, ficando algo como:

```
$user = htmlspecialchars($data['usuario']); //Dado hipotético vindo do banco
$msg = htmlspecialchars($data['mensagem']); //Dado hipotético vindo do banco

echo "<p><strong>$user</strong>:<br>$msg</p>";
```

### Ideia de "templates"

Um cenário que talvez seja interessante seria se as strings fossem armazenadas também e os valores fossem populados, por exemplo em um site com diferentes idiomas, então em arquivos `.ini` ou `.php` você poderia armazenar algo como:

```
./langs/
  +---- pt.ini
  +---- en.ini
  +---- es.ini
```

No conteudo do `pt.ini` teria algo como:

```
main_title=Site %s
main_subtitle=O maior site do seguimento de %s
main_footer=Todos direitos reservados %04d
```

No `en.ini`, algo como:

```
main_title=%s website
main_subtitle=The biggest site in the segment of %s
main_footer=&copy; %04d. All rights reserved

<?php

...

$idioma = $data['usuario_idioma'];
$parsed = parse_ini_file($idioma . '.ini');

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=printf($parsed['main_title'], 'Foo Bar')?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?=printf($parsed['main_title'], 'Foo Bar')?></h1>
    <h2><?=printf($parsed['main_subtitle'], 'tecnologia')?></h2>

    <footer>
        <?=printf($parsed['main_footer'], 'tecnologia')?>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas isto é apenas um exemplo.

---

### Banco de dados e queries

Eu pessoalmente discordo da resposta escolhida que diz isto:

> inserir muitas variáveis em uma string, query

Ao menos **em PHP** especificamente e se query se referir a banco de dados, realmente não tem vantagem, isto porque nas APIs *mysqli* e *PDO* existem os bindParam/bindValue, pois se não usar os binds com ou sem `sprintf` você teria que escapar as variáveis para evitar sql-injetection ou evitar erros de sintaxe na query, mas com os binds das APIs nativas será semelhante ao `sprintf`, por exemplo em *mysqli*:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO Log VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssdd', $user, $language, $score, $percent);

$user = 'Rcs';
$language = 'pt-BR';
$score = 10;
$percent = 11.2;

/* executa */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 3):

A vantagem é mais essa mesmo, legibilidade e facilidade em casos mais complexos. As concatenações não simples precisam de conversões, formatações, e fazer manual dá mais trabalho. E aí entra outra vantagem derivada desta, é muito fácil cometer erros fazendo manualmente, então é uma forma mais robusta também. Provavelmente mais eficiente porque é algo processado em código C e não PHP que é bem mais lento.

Se fizer certo tanto faz no ponto de vista de tradução de aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha visão, ao precisar inserir muitas variáveis em uma string, query, entre outros, ela facilita muito, pois ao concatenar teriamos que abrir e fechar aspas simples e duplas e depois adicionar a concatenação.
No sprintf basta adicionar os termos (%s) para string e (%d) para inteiro (existem varios outros), por exemplo, que a função irá substituir automaticamente. Fica bem mais prático.